# Xamarin IOS NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: ***

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is an Information for all of you who will step in this Exception:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString

[IOS Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofB6P.png)

I have searched a lot for this error in Web and my Code.
But all "NSInvalidArgumentException Reason:" are more specific as ***.

This error only appears on IOS in my Case. Android is working very well. Im mainly deploying on Android to test things. So after serveral of commits i started an IOS deploy and nothing worked anymore.

The Error comes through a ListView with enabled Grouping. 
I'm creating the groups dynamicly with a DueDate given through the ListItems.

My ListView is configured as follow:

```
<ListView x:Name="AuditList"
         ItemSelected="AuditList_ItemSelected"
         HasUnevenRows="True"
         IsGroupingEnabled="true" 
         GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding LongName}"
         GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}"
         SeparatorVisibility="None">
```

As you all know the Binding for a LongName is the Title. 
The ShortName is for IOS only and Responsible for the [Searchlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNM2C.png) on the right.

[Xamarin ListView Grouping Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance)

What I was doing is to create a GroupItem without any ShortName...

```
private GroupedAuditViewItem GetGroup(DateTime date)
    {
        if (date == null)
            return null;
        string longName = CreateGroupName(date);

        return new GroupedAuditViewItem() { LongName = longName };
    }
```

In this cases you will get this Exception. 
But how to prevent this?

You have more than one Path. The simplest would be to delete the ShortName Binding.

```
GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}"
```

An other one is to return a string.Empty ShortName. In this case IOS will display an overlapping empty Searchbar on the right.

```
return new GroupedAuditViewItem() { LongName = longName, ShortName = shortName };
```

You can also prevent this Exception when you have a good Errorhandling for Example a simple `Try Catch`...

I have learned a lot the past days and I hope it will help someone out there who is staying at the same problem :)

Comment: This error explained is, there is Null object reference from where you fetched

Comment: @TosT Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, i have deleted the Shortname Binding in my .XAML so there cant be a NULL:string binding.

Comment: @TosT Great ! You can post it as an answer.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Ok! Thanks for the advise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above there are more than one Path to get rid of this Exception. 
I decided to delete the `GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}"` in my .XAML File.

The advantage is that no ShortNameList will be displayed in the IOS App.